# Javascript try catch scope issue

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

I want to catch the following error: but it doesn't get caught by the try catch - thats because the callback is run in a different stack.

Is there some way to simulate the following code effect, as I need to catch the error in the scope that runs the child process

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process'
const child = spawn('python', ['plot.py', 'non/existing/file.txt'])
child.stdout.on('data', console.log.bind(console))
child.stderr.on('data', console.log.bind(console))

try{
  child.on('close', function(code){
      throw new Error(`some error that doesnt get caught`)
  })
}
catch(e){
  console.log('catch')
  console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: `try...catch` is synchronous, you have to deal with the error asynchronously. Try looking at the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) on how to deal with errors, ie `child.on('error', callback)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the try-catch block in the function.

Then the exception would be catched and from that you can find the error.